# How to make multi table eloquent query in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have two models named as 'Products' and 'Product_options' each product has many options.

I want to select those products that have **at least one option where available is true**.

I've come this far,

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product_options::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

```
$products = Product::whereDoesntHave('options', function ($query) {
                $query->where('available','not', ' 1');
                })
           ->has('options', '>',  0)
           ->get();

dd($products);
```

but if one products has one or more options where avaible is true and one or more options when it is false it doesnt selects the products.

p.s. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... your English is fine, probably better than some native speakers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `whereHas`. It defaults to `>= 1` for the count:

```
Product::whereHas('options', fn ($q) => $q->where('available', true))
    ->get();
```

Should read as, get all products that have any options where 'available' is 'true'.